# import module in Django

Tags: python, django, import

I have a project with structure like on this picture.
[Folders structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAbhM.png)

Where 'backend' folder is Django project folder.
I need to import module from another folder 'main' inside Django app file, i.e. import main.Text_Generator in backend.app.views file.

I tried: `from ...main.Text_Generator import *`. This raise an error while running a server: "attempted relative import beyond top-level package"

And `from main.Text_Generator import *`, also error "No module named 'main'"

What is the correct way to do such import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append("..")
```

And then you should be able to get it with:

```
from main.Text_Generator import *
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using a module outside your Django project. I would recommend moving the folder inside your project directory [or app directory] rather than messing with your PATH. If you move `main` inside `backend` your existing stuff will work.